# Join with relation between two models not working using non integer primary keys

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent, foreign-keys

I have two models: `Holiday` and `HolidayInfo`. These look like as follow:

**`Holiday`**:

```
class Holiday extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'holidays';
    protected $primaryKey = 'holiday_id';
    public $timestamps = false;
    public function dates(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\HolidayDates', 'holiday_id');
    }
    public function images(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\HolidayImages', 'holiday_id');
    }
    public function info(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\HolidayInfo', 'holiday_id');
    }
    public function pricing(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\HolidayPricing', 'holiday_id');
    }
}
```

**`HolidayInfo`**:

```
class HolidayInfo extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'holiday_info';
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $primaryKey = 'holiday_id';
    public function holiday(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Holiday', 'holiday_id');
    }
}
```

My tables:

[image]
[image]

How can I make use of these models in relation to each-other in my controller while also using a simple where clause? In other words, HolidayInfo has some information which I need as-well as Holiday but it would be more efficient to perform a join somehow and then perform a where statement to narrow the data.

This is what i've tried but it didn't return the correct data:

```
$holidays = Holidays::with('info')->get();
```

This is what was returned - as you can see 'info' was returned null.
[image]

I have also tried adding a conditional as suggested by iCoders:

```
Holidays::where('country', $country)->with('info')->get();
```

Which returns the following suggesting that a join hasnt been performed:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'country' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from holidays where country = australia)
```

Country is part of the 'holiday_info' table.

However; performing this query returns the data I need from Holiday Info Table, but it leaves out the Holiday Table data.

`$holiday_info = Holidays::find(0)->info()->where('country', $country)->get();`

After running the following, over 60 results appear, so the SQL works fine just not the laravel:

```
SELECT * from holidays JOIN holiday_info ON holidays.holiday_id = holiday_info.holiday_id
```

How can I combine both models/relations and their data so I can use it in one place?

Comment: For you to get this far, I suppose you have tried to do it some ways. Perhaps you can share a snippet of how you have attempted it so that those who answer could give specific answer and avoid 'giving' those to 'try'.

Comment: @OmisakinOluwatobi done :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @iCoders for helping me crack this case.

The issue was   `public $incrementing = false;` should have been set in the Holiday modal because its a non-integer primary key.

Comment: @iCoders Thanks for being helpful - But didnt 100% solve the problem (though it helped me solve it :) ) . This one liner will help many so i'll leave it up here for reference. I'll mark this as the solution (when im able), Thanks again!!

Answer (score 2):

Yuo have already added relation in Holiday model

```
public function info(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\HolidayInfo', 'holiday_id');
    }
```

You can do something like this using `with`

```
Holiday::where(your condition)->with('info')->get();
```

Updated

```
   public function info(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\HolidayInfo', 'holiday_id','holiday_id');
    }
```

if you are not using laravel convention for table fields then you to pass primary key and foreign key to relation

Has One Relation

```
hasOne($related, $foreignKey, $localKey )
```

Comment: are you sure you have holiday id in info table

Comment: Yes sir sure do. I'll print screen my database soon

Comment: Done :) Check original post

Comment: Hi iCoders, still not working - I tried this earlier which is why i'm still so confused.

Var dump: https://puu.sh/xJ1Un/596423120a.png
Controller: https://puu.sh/xJ1Ys/c79a165656.png

Appreciate your help : )

Comment: do you have many records related to holidays in info.if that the case then try hasMany and check

Comment: No it's one to one. One holiday has one holiday info

Comment: can yhou share info model

Comment: looks good.can you comment primary null .and chekc it.just guessing

Comment: also change primary key and foreign key  data type to varchar to int in database

Comment: Do laravel models require an integer based primary key??

Comment: not sure about it.usually i use int.just guessing now since your relation is proper so

Answer (score 0):

Just use eloquent

```
$holidays = Holiday::where(your condition)->with("info")->get();
```

Then when getting the value on your info, just use:

```
foreach($holidays as $holiday){
    $holiday->info->youInfoFieldHere
}
```

Comment: Many queries will be run using this method, eager-loading would be more efficient in this case, don't you think so?

Comment: @OmisakinOluwatobi that's correct. I've updated my answer